# Setting ClassPath commandline argument while running application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-classpath

I am running Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and executing against Java JRE 1.8. I don't have admin rights on my machine so I am unable to set the ClassPath Environment Varibale. I was doing some reading on the Java Docs help page (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#BEHJBHCD) and it says that you can use a command switch to specificy the classpath which is actually there prefered method.

Example:

```
java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses ...
```

However, I am still relaivily newer to Java and I am running the application from eclipse directly.

My question is how do I go about setting this up while using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse open `Window` -> `Preferences` from menu and search for classpath. Should be `Java` -> `Build Path` -> `Classpath Variables`. There you add / edit / remove classpath variables as needed.

In your launch configuration open tab `Classpath` and add the variable by clicking on `Advanced`.

Please note, however, that you should be able to define environment variables for your operating system even without admin rights on *user level*.